# Check mark auto populates time of edit - trouble removing that time if unchecked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using a script in conjunction with the check box feature on google sheets. I would like the script to populate the time of edit when the box is checked, and remove that time when the box is unchecked.

What I have so far allows me to update the time when the box is checked, and the time updates again when unchecked.

I am having trouble removing the time when the box is unchecked.

This script uses the principles that an unchecked box = FALSE and a checked box = TRUE

Any help is appreciated

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var sName = s.getName();
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if (r.getColumn() == 1 && sName == 'Dashboard') {
  var row = r.getRow();
  var time = new Date();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  var checkmark = r.getValue();
  if (checkmark == 'FALSE') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G' + row.toString()).setValue('');
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss=e.source;
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  var row=rg.rowStart;
  var col=rg.columnStart;
  var value=e.value;
  if(name!='Dashboard'){return;}
  if (col==1 && name=='Dashboard') {
    if(value=="TRUE") {
      sh.getRange(row,7).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    }else{
      sh.getRange(row,7).setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```